# Error Assigning an Array to an Object Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to assign an element of an object array with a float array inside a loop. The first few lines accomplish this task without any problems, but the variable `FData` is highlighted with the message: `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Object`. Despite searching on the internet, I still do not understand what is causing the error.

```
private void newData(int nF, int nL, int[] nN) {
    Object[] I = new Object[4], W = I, A = I, FError = I, FData = new Object[3];
    I[0] = new float[1052][1052]; I[1] = new float[nF][185][185]; I[2] = new float[nF][nF][34][34]; I[3] = new float[nF][nF][nF][6][6];
    W[0] = new float[nF][128][128]; W[1] = new float[nF][nF][16][16]; W[2] = new float[nF][nF][nF][5][5]; W[3] = new float[nF][nF][nF][nF][6][6];
    A[0] = new float[nF][925][925]; A[1] = new float[nF][nF][170][170]; A[2] = new float[nF][nF][nF][30][30]; A[3] = new float[nF][nF][nF][nF];
    FData[0] = new Object[nL - 1]; FData[1] = new Object[nL]; FData[2] = FData[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < nL; i++) {
        FData[1][i] = new float[nN[i]];
        if (i > 0) FData[0][i - 1] = FData[1][i];
        FData[2][i] = new Float[nN[i]][nN[i] * nN[i + 1]];
    }
    FError[0] = FData[0]; FError[1] = FError[0]; FError[2] = FError[0]; FError[3] = FData[2];
}
```

Comment: This float array is assigned to `I` and not `FData`, and therefore not have anything to do with the error, right? @GBlodgett

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Object[] FData = new Object[3];
```

FData is a one-dimensional array. These accesses are fine:

```
FData[0] = ...;
FData[1] = ...;
FData[2] = ...;
```

These two-dimensional accesses are not:

```
FData[1][i] = ...;
FData[2][i] = ...;
```

The compile-time type of `FData[1]` is `Object`. The compiler doesn't know or care that you've assigned a sub-array `Object[]` to that slot. The compile-time type is `Object`, and you can't use `[]` on an `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

I circumvented the problem by creating a few dummy arrays and adding the result from the loop to `FData`.

```
private void newData(int nF, int nL, int[] nN) throws IOException {
    Object[] I = new Object[4], W = I, A = I, FError = I, FData = new Object[3], t0 = new Object[nL], t1 = t0, t2 = t0;
    I[0] = new float[1052][1052]; I[1] = new float[nF][185][185]; I[2] = new float[nF][nF][34][34]; I[3] = new float[nF][nF][nF][6][6];
    W[0] = new float[nF][128][128]; W[1] = new float[nF][nF][16][16]; W[2] = new float[nF][nF][nF][5][5]; W[3] = new float[nF][nF][nF][nF][6][6];
    A[0] = new float[nF][925][925]; A[1] = new float[nF][nF][170][170]; A[2] = new float[nF][nF][nF][30][30]; A[3] = new float[nF][nF][nF][nF];
    FData[0] = new Object[nL - 1]; FData[1] = new Object[nL]; FData[2] = FData[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < nL; i++) {
        t1[i] = new float[nN[i]];
        if (i > 0) {
            t0[i - 1] = t1[i];
            t2[i - 1] = new float[nN[i - 1]][nN[i - 1] * nN[i]];
        }
        else t2[i] = new float[nN[i]][nN[i] * nN[i + 1]];
    }
    FData[0] = t0; FData[1] = t1; FData[2] = t2;
    FError[0] = FData[0]; FError[1] = FError[0]; FError[2] = FError[0]; FError[3] = FData[2];
    save(new Object[] {I,W,A,FData,FError});
}
```